# Map route between your current location and a fixed marker can't make polylines

Tags: java, android, google-maps, import

I want to make a route between my current location and marker not sure how to follow. I added a marker on the map but it doesn't show the polylines. For example when the user starts the app, they should get a route from their location to the marker.I am really stack on this.

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
 GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
     GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
     LocationListener {

         private GoogleMap mMap;
         ArrayList < LatLng > MarkerPoints;
         GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
         Location mLastLocation;
         Marker mCurrLocationMarker;
         LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

         @
         Override
         protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
             setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

             if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                 checkLocationPermission();
             }
             // Initializing
             MarkerPoints = new ArrayList < > ();

             // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
             SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                 .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
             mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
         }

         /**
          * Manipulates the map once available.
          * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
          * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
          * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
          * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
          * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
          * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
          */
         @
         Override
         public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
             mMap = googleMap;

             //Initialize Google Play Services
             if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                 if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                         Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                     buildGoogleApiClient();
                     mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                 }
             } else {
                 buildGoogleApiClient();
                 mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

                 mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(34.701466, 33.029269)).title("UMAR"));
                 // Already two locations
                 if (MarkerPoints.size() > 1) {
                     MarkerPoints.clear();
                     mMap.clear();
                 }
             }

             // Setting onclick event listener for the map
             mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {

                 @
                 Override
                 public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {


                     // Adding new item to the ArrayList
                     MarkerPoints.add(point);

                     // Creating MarkerOptions
                     MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();

                     // Setting the position of the marker
                     options.position(point);

                     /**
                      * For the start location, the color of marker is GREEN and
                      * for the end location, the color of marker is RED.
                      */
                     if (MarkerPoints.size() == 1) {
                         options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
                     } else if (MarkerPoints.size() == 2) {
                         options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
                     }


                     // Checks, whether start and end locations are captured
                     if (MarkerPoints.size() >= 2) {
                         LatLng origin = MarkerPoints.get(0);
                         LatLng dest = MarkerPoints.get(1);

                         // Getting URL to the Google Directions API
                         String url = getUrl(origin, dest);
                         Log.d("onMapClick", url.toString());
                         FetchUrl FetchUrl = new FetchUrl();

                         // Start downloading json data from Google Directions API
                         FetchUrl.execute(url);
                         //move map camera
                         mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(origin));
                         mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));
                     }

                 }
             });

         }

         private String getUrl(LatLng origin, LatLng dest) {

             // Origin of route
             String str_origin = "origin=" + origin.latitude + "," + origin.longitude;

             // Destination of route
             String str_dest = "destination=" + dest.latitude + "," + dest.longitude;


             // Sensor enabled
             String sensor = "sensor=false";

             // Building the parameters to the web service
             String parameters = str_origin + "&" + str_dest + "&" + sensor;

             // Output format
             String output = "json";

             // Building the url to the web service
             String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/" + output + "?" + parameters;


             return url;
         }

         /**
          * A method to download json data from url
          */
         private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException {
             String data = "";
             InputStream iStream = null;
             HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
             try {
                 URL url = new URL(strUrl);

                 // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
                 urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                 // Connecting to url
                 urlConnection.connect();

                 // Reading data from url
                 iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

                 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

                 StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

                 String line = "";
                 while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                     sb.append(line);
                 }

                 data = sb.toString();
                 Log.d("downloadUrl", data.toString());
                 br.close();

             } catch (Exception e) {
                 Log.d("Exception", e.toString());
             } finally {
                 iStream.close();
                 urlConnection.disconnect();
             }
             return data;
         }

         // Fetches data from url passed
         private class FetchUrl extends AsyncTask < String, Void, String > {

             @
             Override
             protected String doInBackground(String...url) {

                 // For storing data from web service
                 String data = "";

                 try {
                     // Fetching the data from web service
                     data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
                     Log.d("Background Task data", data.toString());
                 } catch (Exception e) {
                     Log.d("Background Task", e.toString());
                 }
                 return data;
             }

             @
             Override
             protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                 super.onPostExecute(result);

                 ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();

                 // Invokes the thread for parsing the JSON data
                 parserTask.execute(result);

             }
         }

         /**
          * A class to parse the Google Places in JSON format
          */
         private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask < String, Integer, List < List < HashMap < String, String >>> > {

             // Parsing the data in non-ui thread
             @
             Override
             protected List < List < HashMap < String, String >>> doInBackground(String...jsonData) {

                 JSONObject jObject;
                 List < List < HashMap < String, String >>> routes = null;

                 try {
                     jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
                     Log.d("ParserTask", jsonData[0].toString());
                     DataParser parser = new DataParser();
                     Log.d("ParserTask", parser.toString());

                     // Starts parsing data
                     routes = parser.parse(jObject);
                     Log.d("ParserTask", "Executing routes");
                     Log.d("ParserTask", routes.toString());

                 } catch (Exception e) {
                     Log.d("ParserTask", e.toString());
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 }
                 return routes;
             }

             // Executes in UI thread, after the parsing process
             @
             Override
             protected void onPostExecute(List < List < HashMap < String, String >>> result) {
                 ArrayList < LatLng > points;
                 PolylineOptions lineOptions = null;

                 // Traversing through all the routes
                 for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
                     points = new ArrayList < > ();
                     lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();

                     // Fetching i-th route
                     List < HashMap < String, String >> path = result.get(i);

                     // Fetching all the points in i-th route
                     for (int j = 0; j < path.size(); j++) {
                         HashMap < String, String > point = path.get(j);

                         double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                         double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                         LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                         points.add(position);
                     }

                     // Adding all the points in the route to LineOptions
                     lineOptions.addAll(points);
                     lineOptions.width(10);
                     lineOptions.color(Color.RED);

                     Log.d("onPostExecute", "onPostExecute lineoptions decoded");

                 }

                 // Drawing polyline in the Google Map for the i-th route
                 if (lineOptions != null) {
                     mMap.addPolyline(lineOptions);
                 } else {
                     Log.d("onPostExecute", "without Polylines drawn");
                 }
             }
         }

         protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
             mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                 .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                 .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                 .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                 .build();
             mGoogleApiClient.connect();
         }

         @
         Override
         public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

             mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
             mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
             mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
             mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
             if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                     Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                 LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
             }

         }

         @
         Override
         public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

         }

         @
         Override
         public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

             mLastLocation = location;
             if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
                 mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
             }

             //Place current location marker
             LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
             MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
             markerOptions.position(latLng);
             markerOptions.title("Current Position");
             markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
             mCurrLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

             //move map camera
             mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
             mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));

             //stop location updates
             if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
                 LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
             }

         }

         @
         Override
         public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

         }

         public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;
         public boolean checkLocationPermission() {
             if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                     Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                 // Asking user if explanation is needed
                 if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                         Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

                     // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                     // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                     // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

                     //Prompt the user once explanation has been shown
                     ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                         new String[] {
                             Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
                         },
                         MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);


                 } else {
                     // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
                     ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                         new String[] {
                             Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
                         },
                         MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
                 }
                 return false;
             } else {
                 return true;
             }
         }

         @
         Override
         public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
             String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
             switch (requestCode) {
                 case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION:
                     {
                         // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                         if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                             // permission was granted. Do the
                             // contacts-related task you need to do.
                             if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                                     Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                                 if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
                                     buildGoogleApiClient();
                                 }
                                 mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                             }

                         } else {

                             // Permission denied, Disable the functionality that depends on this permission.
                             Toast.makeText(this, "permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         }
                         return;
                     }


             }
         }
     }
```

Comment: plz check static two lat-logn pass and draw polylines using above code or not.if its working or not?

Comment: i didn't get that. Should i make two static variables lat and long and then draw the polylines using the code i have in my code?